# How to perform pandas map on different column?

Tags: python, pandas

If I have a mapping like so:

```
mapping_dict = {
    0.0: "I0",
    2.0: "I1",
    4.0: "I2",
    6.0: "I3"
}
```

If I have this mapping, and I want to map it to a different column as I do here currently:

```
ila_df.loc[ila_df.injection_type == 0.0, "strategy"] = "I0"
```

what’s the best way to do this? I’ve used the mapping for the same columns but not entirely sure how to do this comparison for different columns?

Comment: A `for` loop? I'm not sure if there's a more concise way.

Comment: what do you mean by different columns? if I understand your example, `ila_df['strategy'] = ila_df.injection_type.map(mapping_dict)` will map all the values existing in the dictionary.

Comment: ooo yes that would work right!? i think that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

```
ila_df['strategy'] = ila_df.injection_type.map(mapping_dict)
```

is all you need to do.